# How write generic routine for JQuery ajax?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

whenever i use jquery ajax for get and post then i wrote the code as follows

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "MyPage.aspx/ProcessInfo",
data: JSON.stringify(DTO),
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
dataType: "json",
success: function (data) {}

});
```

so i need to know that how could i write a generic routine for jquery ajax call where i can pass request type call GET/POST, URL, DATA TYPE, and DATA. data could be in json 
format or may be like two or three augument. so help me with concept by which i can write generic routine which i can use in any situation for ajax call. where data type is json or not. thanks

Comment: why would you want a different method where you still have to pass in the same information? this makes no sense to me... I could understand building a shorthand where you don't have to pass in the information, however you could simply set the defaults using ajaxSetup... this seems pretty useless.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use jQuery's build int [`$.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) and [`$.post()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) shorthand or, create your own custom wrapper:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function jQuerySubmit(type, url, data, contentType, dataType, handler) {
        $.ajax({
            type: type,
            url: url,
            data: data,
            contentType: contentType
            dataType: dataType,
            success: handler
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: can i call jQuerySubmit straight way like jQuerySubmit("POST","MyPage.aspx/ProcessInfo",DTO,"application/json; charset=utf-8","json",myfunc)

Answer (score 3):

Instead of writing a function for doing something simple like an ajax request, why not overwrite the defaults in the `$.ajax` object.

For example:

If your contentType will always be `"application/json; charset=utf-8"` you could set that as the default with the `$.ajaxSetup` method like this:

```
jQuery.ajaxSetup({
     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
     dataType: "json",
     type: "POST"
});
```

Then you could write your ajax calls with less parameters:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
    url: "MyPage.aspx/ProcessInfo",
    data: JSON.stringify(DTO),
    success: function (data) {}
});
```

If you want to create a function to do this, I would still advise to setup your defaults but you could do something like any of the other answers.

Answer (score 1):

It already designed in jQuery:

GET: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

```
$.get("test.php",
   function(data){
     $('body').append( "Name: " + data.name ) // John
              .append( "Time: " + data.time ); //  2pm
   }, "json");
```

POST: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

```
$.post("test.php", { "func": "getNameAndTime" },
  function(data){
    console.log(data.name); // John
    console.log(data.time); //  2pm
  }, "json");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function makeAjax (type , url , data , content,dataType , succFunc)
{
$.ajax({
type: type ,
url: url ,
data: JSON.stringify(data ),
contentType: content,
dataType: dataType ,
success:succFunc(data)

});
}

makeAjax ("POST","MyPage.aspx/ProcessInfo",DTO,"application/json; charset=utf-8","json",myfunc)

function succFunc(data)
{
}
```